# ngModelChange is not working properly

Tags: html, angular, events, onchange

Am doing max length validation manually

here the code.

```
<input class="inputsyle" [(ngModel)]="Modelvalue" 
(ngModelChange)="variantvaluevalidation(Modelvalue)" type="text" />
```

ts code

```
variantvaluevalidation(obj) {
        if (obj.length > 5) {
            return false;
        }
}
```

> The code running like what a expect. But it allowed to enter more than 5 char. 
>   I have also tried `event.preventdefault()` and `event.stoppropagation`. But it's not working.

Any idea about this? all are appreciated.

Comment: Did you `console.log(obj);` to see what it's logging?

Comment: What do you want to achieve? You don't want more than 5 characters to be entered inside the input?

Comment: am getting my model object value in the console.log()\

Comment: @Kinduser . I know the textbox having max length attribute. But the max length value is coming from database

Comment: But you have entered `5` inside the condition. Should be it dynamic/ flexible?

Comment: I just write here it for a sample to understand .

Comment: Is your question about not allowing the model to have more than 5 length or not show more then 5 letters in the input ?

Comment: won't to show more then 5 letters in the input

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can simply use the `maxlenght` attribute to prevent the user from entering more letters.

```
<input class="inputsyle" [(ngModel)]="Modelvalue" 
(ngModelChange)="variantvaluevalidation(Modelvalue)" maxlength='5' type="text" />
```

and if you need to set the maxlength dynamically you can simply bind it to a variable in the controller.

```
<input class="inputsyle" [(ngModel)]="Modelvalue" 
    (ngModelChange)="variantvaluevalidation(Modelvalue)" [attr.maxlength]='maxlength' type="text" />
```

Comment: Sorry . This is not want to me

Comment: Be more precise please. What are you trying to achieve ?

Comment: Read the all my comments under the question

Comment: I read your comment, but you didn't read the last sentence of my answer. Here I edited the answer to provide an exemple of what I said earlier.

Comment: Okay is it working in IE browser? I already tried this man :)

Comment: I also tried it. but it's not working in IE browser. that's why I go to another way

Comment: be cool. it's working only in latest version of IE. Anyway +1 for your achievement